# Swift animation partly hidden behind HStack

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, z-index

The deal animation, where the cards are flying from the deck to the board, is starting below the HStack. See gif below.

https://media0.giphy.com/media/DJn4SxL3w1KHNL132T/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611fc2521910b3bb777a618d1480ddcb21f7a5a1b2f&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g

I have tried to change the .zIndex of the HStack to be behind the deckBody but this didn't work.

Main viewbody

```
 var body: some View {
            VStack {
                // --------- Top Of Screen -------- //
                ....

                // ------------ Board ------------- //
                gameBody
                
                // ------- Bottom Of Screen ------- //
                HStack{
                    Button("Show Hint"){
                        game.hint()
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    deckBody
                    discardPileBody
                    Button("New Game"){
                        game.newGame()
                    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }.padding(6)
            }
    }
```

deckBody

```
 var deckBody: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(game.deck()){ card in
                CardView(card: card)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: card.id, in: dealingNamespace) <--- matched to gamebody
                    .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .identity, removal: .identity))
                    .zIndex(zIndex(of: card)) <---- see next code snippet
            }
        }
        .frame(width: CardConstants.undealtWidth, height: CardConstants.undealtHeight)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.spring().speed(0.1)){
                game.showCards()
            }
        }
    }
```

zIndex func for displaying the deckBody with the last index first

```
private func zIndex(of card: SetCard) -> Double {
        -Double(game.cards.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == card.id }) ?? 0)
    }
```

How do i make the animation go above the HStack?

Thanks!

Comment: Try making your `.padding()` on the `Stack` be just `.horizontal, .bottom`. I think it may be the top padding causing your issues. Otherwise, this will need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Changing the padding on the HStack didnt work. I just tried making a minimal reproducible example but the animation works as it should there o.O. Im gonna spend some more time looking at the code. Thanks for the comment anyways!

Comment: A lot of times you will find that making the MRE actually gives you your answer. When you strip away the unnecessary and find it works, you can add things back until it doesn't...